# Append JSON code to a JSON created from MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to create dynamically a JSON from a MySQL, which seems fairly easy with this piece of code I found in this thread [Create nested json object using php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155231/create-nested-json-object-using-php-mysql/30157982).
However, I want to add before and after the $json_response some piece of JSON code.

**The main code**

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Places "); 
$json_response = array(); //Create an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $row_array = array();
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];        
    $row_array['image_url'] = $row['image_url'];
    $row_array['subtitle'] = $row['subtitle'];      
    $row_array['buttons'] = array();
    $id = $row['id'];


    $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Places where id=$id");
    while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
    {
        $row_array['buttons'][] = array(
            'type' => $opt_fet['type'],
            'caption' => $opt_fet['caption'],
            'url' => $opt_fet['url'],
        );

    }
    array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
}

echo json_encode($json_response,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Produces this JSON**

```
    [
        {
            "title": "Name of the place",
            "image_url": "image.jpg",
            "subtitle":Additional info",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "type": "'url'",
                    "caption": "More Info",
                    "url": "https://some link "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Name of the place 2",
            "image_url": "image2.jpg",
            "subtitle":Additional info2",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "type": "'url'",
                    "caption": "More Info",
                    "url": "https://some link 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**I have somehow to add the following code before the already created JSON**

```
{
  "version": "v2",
  "content": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "type": "cards",
        "elements":
```

**And this code in the end**

```
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
$final_json = [
    "version" => "v2",
    "content" => [
        "messages" => [[
            "type" => "cards",
            "elements" => $json_response
        ]]
    ]
];

echo json_encode($final_json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Personally, I'd rename `$json_response` to `$messages` for clarity purposes.

Comment: Cool, and how would be with adding the code in the end? Or it add it automatically

Comment: Yeah I have noticed after I wrote my comment :)

Comment: It throws an error --- syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']' --- that's on the line "version": "v2",

Comment: @lStoilov Sorry, fixed (Array syntax in PHP is `=>` not `:`).

Comment: @FrankerZ, thanks... I just noticed that the   {
        "type": "cards",
        "elements": is missing :) Can you help adding it too.

Comment: I'm confused as to where you want the actual messages to go then @lStoilov. `"messages"` is an array, so where exactly do you want that object to go? Furthermore, use this as a jump start: If this isn't perfect, try modifying/changing the array yourself. It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I have just altered this line "messages" => [ to "messages" => [[ to serve my purpose. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

While declaring array `$json_response = array();` you can actually prepare it with your default values require like

```
$stdObj=new \stdClass();
$stdObj->version="V2";
$stdObj->content=(object)["messages"=>(object)["type"=>'cards','elements'=>$row_array['buttons']]];

echo json_encode($stdObj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks, there is an error somewhere in the third line - it says: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

Comment: Updated the answer ] was missing

Comment: Why convert everything from an array, back to an object?

Comment: We can achieve the result @FrankerZ by the methoed you have specified, but this is also one possible way.